# Problem in creating causal model for delay analysis

Tags: python, causality

knock-on" are defined as delays caused by previous late departures or arrivals. I am trying to create a model which can help predict the arrival delay of the next flights.
But I don't know where to start. turnaround time is the time which an 
Any suggestions on where should I begin. 
Turnaround time is defined as the time required to unload an airplane after its arrival at the gate and to prepare it for departure again.

I am working on python.

[image: Sample Dataset]

Comment: So if there is a delay of say 60 mins you want to add 60 mins to all subsequent flights? As ion their departure time, arrival, and so on?

Comment: actually, 65% of flights get delayed because of this knock on delay. And it is not true in every model. Is there a way to predict delay in the next flight because of previous flight. Adding 60 mins is nothing but cumulative sum. Which I don't wanna do

Comment: So what is the objective here? To predict whether / which fligths will be delayed? Or to predict which flights will be delayed because of "knock-on"? To predict by how much will flights delay if there is "knock-on"?

Comment: To predict by how much will flights delay if there is knock-on ?

Comment: So if the flight is delayed by 60 minutes and the turnaround time is 30 then if it had more than 90 minutes before its next duty it will not be delayed? I suggest editing your question to clarify what your terms all mean and exactly what your question is. Perhaps a few specific examples of situation like the one Isuggest might help. If you are asking for Python help then that is off-topic here and you need another site.